# How to get rid of array/object casting in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Some methods/functions only accept/return arrays, others only get/give objects. In my day to day PHP programming I have to repetitively convert objects to array and vice versa. (`(object) ['x'=>3]` and `(array) (new stdClsss())`).

Most classes do not implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). Smartly in JavaScript, these two syntaxes are interchangeable. Is there any hack, workaround to stick to one of them and get rid of variable casting and "Cannot use object of type xxx as array in " or "Cannot use object of type stdClass as arhray in "Cannot access property on non-object" messages.

Comment: *Why* are you casting those back and forth? For what purpose?

Comment: @deceze To send them to other functions/methods that only accept one of them.

Comment: Functions you wrote yourself or PHP functions?

Comment: @deceze PHP functions and 3rd party libraries and frameworks.

Comment: Well, arrays and objects are different beasts in PHP. The best you can do, if you can't harmonise your types across functions in general, is to put them in some adapter object class which has all the magic getters and setters to allow them to be used either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with [ary](https://github.com/salarmehr/ary).

```
$var= ary(['x' => 'foo', 'y' => 'bar']);
$foo = $var->x; //or
$foo = $var['x'];
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using  php serializing function, instead of trying to convert them.

```
$array = array();
$obj = serialize($array);
$again = unserialize($obj);
```

This will help you if your interchange is about to save datum.

if, working with the object is your bulk task, try to define a class library for your object and then, implement your function like `ToArray()`, `ToString()`, `ToObject()` or `ToStorable()`, instead of converting them in your code with natural functions.

Comment: How is serialising an array turning it into an object, or help with turning it into an object...?!

Comment: It's more efficient to stick to the casting method